# Зависимость модулей

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть три куска кода:

**index.js**

```
const module1 = require('./1');
const module2 = require('./2');
```

**1.js**

```
const methods = require('./2');
console.log('hello from 1');
console.log('1', methods);
module.exports = {
    foo() {console.log('one')},
    test() {console.log(module)},
};
```

**2.js**

```
const methods = require('./1');
console.log('hello from 2');
console.log('2', methods);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(methods);
}, 1000);
module.exports = {
    foo() {console.log('two')},
    test() {console.log(module)},
};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в консоли после выполнения таймаута, выведет пустой объект ? И если поменять в **1.js** строки с экспортом модуля на

```
module.exports.foo = function() {console.log('foo')};
module.exports.test = function() {console.log(module)};
```

, то в консоли выведет заполненный объект функцией foo и содержимым модуля? В спецификации написано, что *module* не является глобальным объектом. Тогда почему происходит перезаписывание ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Потому что когда вы из модуля 2 вызвали модуль 1, он вернул дефолтный объект `module.exports`, который создаётся нодов при инициализации модуля.

Позже вы заменили его на другой объект (`module.exports = {...}`), но модуль 2 уже закешировал неактуальную копию.

Поэтому надо избегать таких циклов, а если по каким-то причинам так сделать не получается, то не заменять `module.exports`, а добавлять методы в него.

Например можно сделать так:

```
// 1.js
const methods = require('./2');
console.log('hello from 1');
console.log('1', methods);
Object.assign(module.exports, {
    foo() {console.log('one')},
    test() {console.log(module)},
});
```

Comment: А почему бы не использовать `exports.foo = '...'; exports.test = '...';` вместо `Object.assign`? Проще же

Comment: Это по вкусу. Мне, например, не нравиться десять раз повторять `exports`.